# Yocto setup.py requires pyserial

Tags: python, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to package https://github.com/kliment/Printrun in a Yocto recipe but cannot get it working. My recipe currently looks as follows:

```
LICENSE = "AGPLv3"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=d32239bcb673463ab874e80d47fae504"

PV = "2.7"
SRCREV = "0193a9dbe31458c45059bf2dcb0a9905b7bb06fc"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/kliment/Printrun.git;protocol=git;branch=master"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python-cython \
                  python-pyserial \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit distutils
```

I am assuming this is what I need to do because it has a setup.py that inherits from distutils? If so, this does not work and I get an error complaining about a lack of the serial module:

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
WARNING: Failed to cythonize: No module named Cython.Build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 36, in <module>
    from printrun.printcore import __version__ as printcore_version
  File "/home/gerhard/Jethro/yocto/build/out-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-vfp-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/printrun/2.7-r0/git/printrun/printcore.py", line 20, in <module>
    from serial import Serial, SerialException, PARITY_ODD, PARITY_NONE
ImportError: No module named serial
ERROR: python setup.py build execution failed.
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/gerhard/Jethro/yocto/build/out-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-vfp-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/printrun/2.7-r0/temp/log.do_compile.15542)
```

I would also like to be able to compile the small cythonable module with cython. For some reason both cython and psyerial are not availible even though I added them as rdepends, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error states that there's a log file, did you look at it ?

Comment: @stdcall Yes, that error block is the log file

Comment: Did you google for `Failed to cythonize: No module named Cython.Build`

Comment: Yes, but that is a custom message from this project with no hits so I'm guessing no one has tried it with yocto yet which isn't a surprise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added dependency on python cython only on runtime. I guess you need to add also for compilation.

```
DEPENDS_${PN} = "python-cython \
                  python-pyserial"
```

Comment: not strange.  it clearly states that the package is missing and it can't find it.  are you sure it exists?

Comment: Yes, if I just install python-pyserial and then run the program on the device then it runs fine. I'm thinking that having the setup script depend on it is crazy though and will just patch that away.